# (instanceof DateTime) returns false on a instance of DateTime

Tags: php

When I `var_dump($value);`, 
I get

```
class DateTime#737 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(26) "2016-01-24 21:00:52.000000"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(15) "Europe/Brussels"
}
```

But when I do `var_dump($value instanceof DateTime);` 
I expect it to return true, but it returns false

Do I miss something here ?

Comment: Are you perhaps in a namespace?

Comment: Omg thank you @deceze I was in a namespace and I forgot to use DateTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason this might fail is if `DateTime` in your source code does not actually refer to the right `DateTime` class. This may happen if you're in a namespace:

```
namespace Foo;

$bar instanceof DateTime;  // means Foo\DateTime
```

Either `use DateTime` or explicitly refer to the global `\DateTime` class.